# Code coverage won't display in Sonarqbue when posting trhough sonar scanner

Tags: sonarqube, sonarscanner

Sonarqube server 6.7.7
Sonar scanner 4.6.2

sonar-project.properties

```
sonar.java.binaries=target/classes
#sonar.junit.reportsPath=target/surefire-reports
#sonar.surefire.reportsPath=target/surefire-reports
#sonar.jacoco.reportPaths=target/jacoco.exec
sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths=/target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml
sonar.java.coveragePlugin=jacoco
sonar.verbose=true
```

*Note: I used the jacoco.xml or the jacoco.exec still not able to display*

[sonarqube dashboard showing no code coverage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5Z2p.png)

Comment: There is a great deal of information you're not showing here. Show your build script and the build output. Have you verified the "jacoco.xml" file actually exists at the location you specify?

Comment: Hi yes, the jacoco.xml and jacoco.exec is generated and i actually run sonarqube and sonar scanner manually and I did not use jenkins for this one.

Comment: hi now I realized that xml file should be using the relative path below by adding . before target folder and so far it works.
sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths=./target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml